# Keras: Train different parts of a network on different losses simultaneously

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, backpropagation, pytorch

For example, if I want to train something like a GAN, the discriminator D part will be trying to minimize crossentropy loss, and the generator G part will be trying to maximize the crossentropy loss.

The GAN would be feeding noise into G, G's output into D, and D's output being the final output. For a single input into the GAN, I want D's weights to update with their loss, and G's weights to update with their own loss (which happens to be the negative of D's loss). I want these updates to happen in one shot. I know that you can alternating between training D and then freezing the training of D to train G. But in that case, you always have half of the network being run without its weights being updated. I want to be able to run the network once, and have the different parts of it update with respect to their own losses.

Is this possible in Keras? Or is this even a reasonable thing to ask for?

If not possible in Keras, if it can be done in tensorflow, or even pytorch, that would be alright too.

Comment: don't think this is a good idea for the following reasons: 1) for GAN training, typically you need to balance sensitively how much you train your discriminator, and that may require more or it may require less iterations when for your generator update. 2) you could only make it "happen in one shot" for the samples from your generator anyway, as your generator has nothing to do with forward passes based on real data.

Comment: I'm aware that GANs are typically such a balancing act. Even so, I've found it to often be the case that overly scheduling for/training either G or D could be less stable and more likely to not converge to something good. Also, another reason I'd want this is the cost of G is so much that generating without updating is quite painful. In any case, would it be possible to do this simply in keras or another deep learning framework?

Comment: mh. I am only well familiar with PyTorch. There it would be possible to avoid extra computations of G by doing something like this: 1) Compute sample from G and pass through D to get your final_output 2) compute D loss and call .backward(retain_graph=True) 3) zero G gradients 4) update D network 5) re-use final_output to compute G loss 6) call .backward 7) update G network 8) zero all gradients

Comment: there may be some equivalent to retain_graph available in Keras, that's really the key to my suggestion if you want to cut down on computations of G.